# SSL connection to WebService with invalid certificate workaround not working

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, https, certificate

In my WPF application I want to make a connection with a Web-Service through HTTPS ignoring possible certificate errors, which seems to be a fairly common thing to do, from what I've been researching.

I've found this nifty snippet:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

I've set a breakpoint on the return statement, and it is never called (tried it with a separate method too).

I've also tried setting the following properties to false:

```
ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = false;
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false; //tried true too
ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
```

I've also tried to create my own ICertificatePolicy with a CheckValidationResult that always returns true and attributing it to ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy. That also hasn't worked.

In all of these attempts, I get the following:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive

I've created a separate windows forms application with just three lines:

```
WebReference.MySebService myWebService = new WebReference.MySebService();
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
bool result = myWebService.TestConnection(); 
//TestConnection is a method in my WebService that simply returns true.
```

And it WORKED.

What else could I try ?

Info:

- WPF application
- .NET 3.5
- The web-service is consumed through a separate class
- It works perfectly with regular HTTP
- Not using proxy
- Fails both on the server and with the WS on localhost
- The same three lines that run on my test app, won't work in my WPF app
- The two instances of the WebService are exactly the same (all properties, including URL)
- Tried deleting and re-adding the web-reference just as in my test apps.

Comment: You've shown all the code in your WinForms app - you haven't shown the equivalent for your WPF app.

Comment: The same three lines, copy-pasted into my WPF app don't work too. I've analysed the two instances of my Web-Service, and they are the same. All the flags, and the URL property as well.

Comment: Have you tried using Fiddler as a proxy in its "decrypt HTTPS" mode to see what's happening? It may not be clear... I'd be pretty surprised at the two UIs making any difference to HTTPS comms though. What about a console app?

Comment: I'll try it now. What I thought is that since this line doesn't affect any of my objects, it applies the delegate to some underground part of my .NET runtime, and maybe the type of project affects the runtime, uses a different thread, or something like that.

Comment: My console app attempt: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kWAAR.jpg

Comment: Okay, so it looks like it's something odd which is going on under WPF in particular. That sounds very odd...

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JqprO.jpg Definitelly not WPF too. It's starting to get to me.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/aPiDC.jpg The same lines on my WPF application. This is absolutely the first instance created of the Web-Service, and with the same URL as my test apps.

Comment: This exception message is the portuguese version of "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive". It was the worst idea ever to translate exception messages.

Answer (score 2):

After stressing a lot about this, we've finally come to a solution.

The hint to it was in the inner-exception, which passed unnoticed before. It stated that it failed to load a Security assembly.

Coincidentally we had a project named Security with an output assembly named Security on this solution, which caused a conflict. And it was only incorrectly accessed when SSL was being used.

Interestingly enough, neither Visual Studio, nor the compiler have warned me that this wasn't such a good idea, and not even that there was a .NET assembly named just like ours.

The solution was to rename this assembly, and everything worked perfectly immediately without a flaw.

Lessons learned:

- Use customized names that could never exist already, like
  SPONGEBOBSQUAREPANTS_Security.
- Do not trust that Visual Studio will check if my assembly is conflicting with anything.
- Always check for inner exceptions, no matter how familiar their outer ones may seem.